# Config problems with Spring 3 and Thymeleaf template Engine

Tags: spring-mvc, template-engine, thymeleaf

I have added the following JARs from [Thymeleaf GitHub](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-dist/downloads) to my build path.
 - lib/javassist-3.16.1-GA
 - lib/ognl-3.0.5
 - lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1
 - dist/thymeleaf-spring3-2.0.8

Here is my application-context-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- It allow us to use @Autowire, @Required and @Qualifier annotations. -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>ui</value>
                <value>messages</value>
                <value>exceptions</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <bean id="issuerValidator"
        class="com.company.console.validators.MyValidator" />

    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I get the following error when starting my app (It started fine before adding *templateResolver* and *templateEngine* to my application-context-config.xml.

```
DEBUG [2012-07-17 09:31:29,517] [Thread-2] (XmlBeanDefinitionReader) - Loaded 13 bean definitions from location pattern [/WEB-INF/Resources/*-config.xml]
DEBUG [2012-07-17 09:31:29,517] [Thread-2] (XmlWebApplicationContext) - Bean factory for Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4add8e0d: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,dateFormatter,issuerDaoOilImpl,issuerServiceImpl,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,messageSource,multipartResolver,issuerValidator,templateResolver,templateEngine]; root of factory hierarchy
DEBUG [2012-07-17 09:31:29,547] [Thread-2] (DefaultListableBeanFactory) - Ignoring bean class loading failure for bean 'templateResolver'
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver] for bean with name 'templateResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/Resources/applicationContext-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:396)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    ... 17 more
DEBUG [2012-07-17 09:31:29,549] [Thread-2] (DefaultListableBeanFactory) - Ignoring bean class loading failure for bean 'templateEngine'
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine] for bean with name 'templateEngine' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/Resources/applicationContext-config.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:396)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    ... 29 more
```

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok....so I added the following to my application-context-config.xml:

```
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
  <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
</bean>
```

And added dist/thymeleaf-2.0.8 to my build path also.

New docs are [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html).
[This](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#preface) doc will probably have info on configuring spring.

Works now.

Comment: tutorial link is broken

Comment: Looks like they have changed their links guys.
You will probably find info in this link:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html

Answer (score 0):

> **Added pom.xml**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.unbescape/unbescape -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.unbescape</groupId>
    <artifactId>unbescape</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```